# Custom printing Odd pages or Even pages in XtraReport

Tags: silverlight, printing, xtrareport

I have a project in Silverlight. I export XtraReport with all pages on IE, then I would like to custom printing Odd Pages or Even Pages  (like utilities ptrint in Word but print immediate from report in brower). Help me, please!.....

Comment: "print immediate in web" - you mean print directly from the browser? You mean add different headers and footers on odd and even pages? I suspect you'd need to ask the XtraReport people sorry, or if it's not an XtraReport problem you haven't given us enough information to help you.

Comment: Thanks  for read my topic. I have update my answwer, please review it and help me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know XtraReport and my Silverlight is rusty - I don't think I can help you myself.

Comment: Nonetheless thank you for reply. Have a nice day, Rup!